# Phonegap alert dialog shows index.html on top of message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm working on a phonegap app which i implemented some dialog warning messages such as no internet connection and push notification, now the problem I'm facing is that when i get any type of dialog i get index.html in top off the message, how can i get rid off it?

```
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  //Check Internaet Connection
  function onOnline() {               
              ("")
  }
  document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
  function onOffline() {
      alert("No estas conectado al internet")
  }
      document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
      </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Dialogs plugin instead:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dialogs

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

Then you can replace all calls to `alert()` with:

```
navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])
```

Example:

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

Just be aware that the standard `alert()` blocks script execution, while the plugin version is non-blocking and hence provides an optional callback.

Comment: I did that and I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: But did you also change to using navigator.notification.alert?

Comment: Do you mean this plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />?

Comment: I get it now i just had to replace alert to navigator.notification.alert. thanks.

Comment: @Simon East Hi can u help? I'm trying to implement navigator.notification.confirm() for when the user presses "log out". My confirm box says "are you sure you wish to log out?" if the user presses ok then I want to call function called onConfirmLogOut() and if they press cancel I want to execute nothing.. I thought I had it correct however the onConfirmLogOut() function is being called even if they press cancel. My code: navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you wish to log out?", onConfirmLogOut);
function onConfirmLogOut(){
 localStorage.clear();
 closeSideMenu();
}