# ionic alert display index.html as title in iOS but work fine with android

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am facing an issue with ionic alert , i build an application with using ionic , i use alerts some where in code for validation purpose , it works good in android but in iOS it display index.html as it's title , i googled but have not found any solution to it .So i am posting my question here on stackOverflow ..I do got one link during me RnD but it was not useful to me , Here is the link :-

[Phonegap alert dialog shows index.html on top of message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696106/phonegap-alert-dialog-shows-index-html-on-top-of-message)

Here i am posting all plugin list :-

```
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.5.0 "PushPlugin"
cordova-plugin-admob 2.16.1 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.18.0 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 0.10.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.1.5 "Custom URL scheme"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.2.4 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-speechrecognizer 1.0.0 "SpeechRecognizer"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.0.12-dev "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.5.0 "Toast"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer 0.8.2 "EmailComposer"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 5.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"
```

Here is the piece of code :-

```js
var myPopup = $ionicPopup
  .alert({
      template: '<div  class="pop_bx"><label> Name</label><input type="text"  ng-model="data.name"> <br/><label> Email</label><input type="email"  ng-model="data.email"> <br/><label> Telephone</label><input type="tel"  ng-model="data.telephone"> <br/><label>Comment</label> <textarea name="textarea" ng-model="data.message"></textarea></div>',
      scope: $scope,
      cssClass: 'yourclassfeedback',
      buttons: [{
            text: $translate
              .instant('contactPage.btnCancel')
          },
          {
            text: 'Submit',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {
              console.log(e);

              if (!$scope.data.name) {
                alert('Please enter name');
              } else if (!$scope.data.email) {
                alert($translate
                  .instant('contactPage.emailvaid'));
              } else if (!$scope.data.message) {
                alert($translate
                  .instant('contactPage.message'));
              }
            });
```

Have any-body here on stack-overflow face this issue and solve it , is it possible to solve it ? I am just facing this issue in iOS in Android it's working fine.

Any help would be Greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this code, and please embaled `$ionicPopup` in cotroller.

```
 var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'Please enter name',
     template: ''
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , But i am already displaying it over IonicPopup. I updated my question you see over there.

Comment: ok can you use cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs this plugin for that here is a link http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/dialogs/ .  its look like native ios and android dialog.

Comment: But it closing my Feedback popup  automatically